# How can I find out what my default gateway should be?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, gateway

I have a linux (RHEL 7) server on a network and the default gateway is set incorrectly. How can I find out what the default gateway should be, without asking a Network Administrator?

Comment: You can make a few educated guesses, such as trying `.1` and `.254`, but that's pretty much about it. GW not included in DHCP response?

Comment: The IP addresses are set statically, I was worried using `dhclient` or something might overwrite the IPs `ifcfg-*` files. But I will try that regardless.

Comment: @Panki Using `.1` or `.254` really only works reliably in a `/24` subnet. Other netmasks can give you radically different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to another host on the same network segment, look at its TCP settings.  Chances are, the same Default Gateway will work for another host on the same segment.  Do not assign the same IP address.

If the IP address of the RHEL7 host was set via DHCP and it was assigned a different (presumably incorrect) Default Gateway, this is something you *should* bring to the attention of your network administrator.  It is entirely possible, however, that the MAC address of the host in question was also specifically identified by said administrator and given a specific entry in the DHCP server settings to assign "abnormal" configurations to this host, for reasons likely beyond the scope of this question.

If the IP address of the host was set manually, by hand, you should *still* consult the network administrator to ensure that you do not (or did not) select an IP address which is already in use by or assigned to another device which connects to the same network (or is in the DHCP pool and may thereby be assigned *to* another device on the network).

Comment: I think you are right to look at a similar working server and compare configurations. I also agree with you that this is a thing that should be brought up the Network Admins. I am thinking this question would have been better suited for server exchange.